# Why can't I specialize a generic function in scala?

Tags: scala, template-specialization, specialized-annotation

I get an error saying `type N is unused or used in non-specializable positions.`, for the method with the following signature:

```
protected def offsetFrom0[@specialized(Int,Long) N](offsetFrom1 : Codec[N])(implicit N : Integral[N]) : Codec[N]
```

Can someone explain to me in layman's terms what the rules are around specialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@specialized` annotation can be used both for class and method type parameters.

```
def gethead[@specialized(Int,Float,Double) T: Numeric](items: T*): T = items(0)
gethead(4,57,32) // Result: 4
```

So in your case you can do something along the lines of:

```
case class Offset[@specialized(Int, Long) N](offsetFrom1: N) {
    def offsetFrom0: N = ???
}

Offset(1).offsetFrom0
Offset(1L).offsetFrom0
```